# On Error GoTo ErrHand(C#)

Tags: c#, error-handling

How in C# if I have error can I send it to an error handling line like below. I know how to do it in visual basic, but need a little assistance in C#. Thanks for the help

```
Sub Main()
On Error GoTo ErrHand
....Code Here
End Sub

ErrHand:
  MsgBox "Message Here"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The On Error GoTo pattern is upgraded in .NET to:

```
try
{
   // Execute your code
}
catch  <ExceptionType>
{
 // Handle exception
}
finally
{
 // Cleanup resources
}
```

The following link [Error Handling Transformation](http://www.artinsoft.com/vbc_errorhandling.aspx) should give you some info.

Comment: Couple things to note - finally isn't required, but it's good to have if you have any resources to release (Usually this is some kind of Stream). You can also set up multiple catch statements to deal with different kinds of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks that will definately help me out I am glad you can use multiple catch's because there are plenty of different senarios. really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
   //your code here
}
catch
{
   // error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of C# basic information, time for a little training?

```
try
{
    //Code here
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    HandleExeption(ex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can be done (logically) but it ain't purdy

```
  bool TestMethod()
    {
        string _errorMessage = string.Empty;
        bool returnValue = true;
        try
        {
            int x;
            throw new Exception("Force Call To Error Handler");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorMessage = ex.ToString();
            goto errHandler;
        }

        //Other code here

        exitCode:
        ;
        return returnValue;

    //Exit code here

    errHandler:
        ;
        //Error Code Here
        returnValue = false;
        goto exitCode;
    }
```